# Script for temporarily disabling internet connection

Tags: linux, networking, bash, sudo

I want to block internet connection to me for about 8 hours or so on my Linux machine. I have no will power, so simple call for

```
ifconfig down
ifconfig up
```

or similar commands doesn't apply to me, because I "know" how to bypass it.

I'm expecting that this algorithm will work

1. Disable internet connection via shutting down network interfaces or via

   ```
   iptables -I INPUT -j DROP
   ```

   and save iptables config so that I couldn't bypass that via reboot.
2. Disable any root/sudo privileges for all users. Or maybe change root/sudo password to random string.
3. Do that in reverse after certain period of time.

Usually I don't have an emergencies when I need an internet connection, so this method doesn't have to have way to bypass it on demand.

Could anyone provide me some correct, and more important, safe way to do that? I don't want to somehow lose superuser rights in my system at all, because of mistake that I will surely make in my script.

Comment: The only way to lock yourself out is to have someone else swallow the key (or at least not tell you). I don't know of a way without getting someone else involved.

Comment: How about creating a new user with sudo abilities, restricting the time it can log in (using pam_time). Remove your ordinary user account from the sudoers file. The use cron to modify your firewall or whatever. The real problem is that if you have physical access, you can always go into single user mode.

Comment: @lzam if it will be really painful to bypass block, i think i could show some will power and stop myself at the way. But it should be REALLY painful, like many reboots, some hard to remember commands and other "couldn't automatically be done" work.

Comment: I can't help but wonder if improving your will power would be a better answer to all this. The mind is a thing that can and will improve with practise.